# Why doesn't Spring use my PrincipalExtractor bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Spring doesn't want to use my `PrincipalExtractor` bean. Instead it uses default `FixedPrincipalExtractor`.

I'm trying to follow Spring's tutorial to OAuth2:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

And everything went almost fine untill I decided to save an authenticated user to my database. The tutorial simply says: "It's too easy, so we won't show how to do this". Of course that is a moment where I've been stuck for days.

There is `WebSecurityConfig` class. It's a mess but it's used for educational purposes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/js/**", "/error**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(google(), "/login/google"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);

        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google")
    public ClientResources google() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);

        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor(UserDetailsRepo userDetailsRepo) {
        return map -> {
            String id = (String) map.get("sub");
            User user = userDetailsRepo.findById(id).orElseGet(() -> {
                User newUser = new User();

                newUser.setId(id);
                newUser.setEmail((String) map.get("email"));
                // and so on...

                return newUser;
            });

            return userDetailsRepo.save(user);
        };
    }
}

class ClientResources {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

And `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_db
    username: postgres
    password: password
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true

google:
  client:
    clientId: 437986124027-7072jmbsba04d11fft0h9megkqcpem2t.apps.googleusercontent.com
    clientSecret: ${clientSecret}
    accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    scope: openid,email,profile
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
    preferTokenInfo: true
```

As I wrote above, Spring doesn't really want to use my `PrincipalExtractor` bean and uses default `FixedPrincipalExtractor` instead. I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue but nothing helps. Except for changing `application.yml` like this:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 620652621050-v6a9uqrjq0ejspm5oqbek48sl6od55gt.apps.googleusercontent.com
      clientSecret: ${clientSecret}
  [...]
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
      preferTokenInfo: true
```

There was `google.client.clientId` and it changes to `security.oauth2.client.clientId` as you can see.

And if you delete all the filter methods and everything related to them, then it works, yes. It does use my `PrincipleExtractor`. But how can I add more authentication providers (Facebook, GitHub, etc) and local authentication now?

Finally, I have a few questions:

1. How to make Spring use my `PrincipalExtractor`?
2. Should I use `PrincipalExtractor` at all? Maybe there is another way to do the same?
3. Is something wrong with my `application.yml`?

Things I tried:

1. Adding the @EnableAuthorizationServer ([Why is my spring @bean never instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867437/why-is-my-spring-bean-never-instantiated))

Nothing changes.

2. Adding ResourceServerTokenServices ([PrincipalExtractor and AuthoritiesExtractor doesn't hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206247/principalextractor-and-authoritiesextractor-doesnt-hit))

Spring can't find UserInfoRestTemplateFactory. Adding the bean manually is not right I guess, and simply doesn't work.

3. Many different solutions. None of them worked.

Comment: Facing the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

When you are defining your `ssoFilter` add something like this:

```
tokenServices.setPrincipalExtractor(myCustomPrincipalExtractor());
```

Bonus: the same goes for `AuthorityExtractor`.